# Website which worked fine in IE9 with Documents Mode IE7 is having issues in IE11 with IE7 Standard as Document Mode

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-11

My website which worked in IE9 with Documents Mode IE7 standards is failing with CSS issues in IE11 with IE7 standards Documents Mode.

I'm enforcing IE7 standards Documents Mode in web.config file while rendering in IE11 using

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=IE7" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Ideally i suppose there should n't be any issues as IE7 documents Mode in IE9 vs IE7 documents Mode in IE11. correct me if i'm wrong.

Doc Type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

As of now i see, too many CSS issues because of Padding & margin-tops.

Am i missing something, Please let me know if there is a way to make my website work in IE11 with Documents Mode IE7 work almost same as IE9 with Documents Mode IE7.

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft first released IE11, they announced that [legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384051(v=vs.85).aspx) were deprecated.  Originally introduced with IE8, they were originally meant as temporary measures to give web developers time to rewrite their sites to use HTML5 markup and other modern practices.  That time has passed; document modes will not be supported moving forward.  They are not, for example, supported today by the IE11 Windows Store experience or by Windows store apps.  They will not be supported by Spartan, the new browser replacing IE in Windows 10.

IE11 also removed certain [legacy features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#legacyAPIs) to encourage web developers to rely more heavily on modern, interoperable features.  And they've continued to update IE11 to [further this transition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn736066(v=vs.85).aspx).

Your best solution is to bite the bullet and update your markup to reflect modern practices and standards.  The good news is that many of these changes will help you also support other modern browsers.

The modern.ie site has a [compatibility scanner](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/compat-scan) that gives you a report of some of the major changes.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance